# Resorting Arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string

I receive data that I need to output in a string of the format:

```
123 - A, B, C
234 - A
345 - B
567 - B, C
789 - C
```

The data I get is sorted by letter (A, B, or C) and then given to me by number.  So I have three dynamic arrays like:

```
ArrayA(1) = 123
ArrayA(2) = 234
ArrayB(1) = 345
ArrayB(2) = 123
ArrayB(3) = 567
ArrayC(1) = 123
ArrayC(2) = 789
ArrayC(3) = 567
```

Notice that the index corresponding to a particular 3-digit number in a given array does not necessarily correspond to the same 3-digit number, e.g. ArrayA(1)=123=ArrayB(2).

The arrays are of arbitrary length (there could be any number of numbers in A, B, or C) but there are only three arrays.

This makes it easy to output something such as:

```
123 - A
234 - A
345 - B
123 - B
567 - B
123 - C
789 - C
567 - C
```

but this is NOT my desired result.

**I need it in this format:**

```
123 - A, B, C
234 - A
345 - B
567 - B, C
789 - C
```

To play with this problem directly, here's some code that generates the "easy" string:

```
Dim ArrayA(2), ArrayB(3), ArrayC(3) As Integer, Output As String
ArrayA(1) = 123
ArrayA(2) = 234
ArrayB(1) = 345
ArrayB(2) = 123
ArrayB(3) = 567
ArrayC(1) = 123
ArrayC(2) = 789
ArrayC(3) = 567

For i=1 to 2
     Output = Output & ArrayA(i) & " - A" & vbNewLine
Next i
For i=1 to 3
     Output = Output & ArrayB(i) & " - B" & vbNewLine
Next i
For i=1 to 3
     Output = Output & ArrayC(i) & " - C" & vbNewLine
Next i

MsgBox(Output)
```

As mentioned above, I'm hoping to move the format such that it is organized by three-digit number, rather than by letter.

---

My best attempt at a solution would be to try to write the data into an excel sheet, sort it appropriately, and pull it back into VBA, which seems unnecessarily ugly.  For example:

```
For i=1 to Len(ArrayA)+Len(ArrayB)+Len(ArrayC)
    If i < Len(ArrayA) Then
        Range("A:"&i).Value = ArrayA(i)
        Range("B:"&i).Value = "A,"
    End If
    If i > Len(ArrayA) And i <= Len(ArrayA) + Len(ArrayB) Then
        Range("A:"&i).Value = ArrayB(i)
        Range("B:"&i).Value = Range("B:"&i).Value & "B,"
    End If
    if i >= Len(ArrayA)+Len(ArrayB) Then
        Range("A:"&i).Value = ArrayC(i)
        Range("B:"&i).Value = Range("B:"&i).Value & "C,"
Next i
```

Then I could sort this, search out duplicates, and properly combine them, and finally get to the correct output of:

```
123 - A, B, C
234 - A
345 - B
567 - B, C
789 - C
```

Comment: I confused: do you start with a string (as mentioned in your opening sentence) or a bunch of arrays (as mentioned in your third sentence)? Your code also just seems to generate 3 arrays. Where is your attempts to achieve the desired result?

Comment: I apologize.  I start with a bunch of arrays; I initially generated the output string as a final result, but now I need to go back and rewrite the format.  I'll clarify.

As for my attempts, I've written some pretty heavyhanded attempts to write the values into an Excel sheet and sort out the duplicates, but I didn't think there was value in it.  I'll include that as well.'

Comment: Just a note: `Dim ArrayA(2), ArrayB(3), ArrayC(3) As Integer` is the same as `Dim ArrayA(2) As Variant, ArrayB(3) As Variant, ArrayC(3) As Integer` . Also `ArrayA(2)` is equivalent of `ArrayA(0 to 2)`, unless using `Option Base 1`

Comment: You've put some great effort in this question, but a picture on how it looks, and how you expect the result always helps. I'm still trying to understand what you are looking to achieve... you've mentioned: `but this is NOT my desired result.`, and shown what is not... would just be great to show what would be the `desired result`.

Comment: The desired result is the list:


123 - A, B, C

234 - A

345 - B

567 - B, C


789 - C

I will clarify this in my main post. Thank you. And thank you for the Dim info, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Sub PopulateFromArrays()

Call WriteArray(ArrayA, "A")
Call WriteArray(ArrayB, "B")
Call WriteArray(ArrayC, "C")

End Sub


Function WriteArray(MyArray, MyString)

i = 2
For j = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    ValueFound = False
    k = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To k
        If Range("A" & i).Value = MyArray(j) Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).Value & ", " & MyString
            ValueFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If ValueFound = False Then
        Range("A" & k + 1).Value = MyArray(j)
        Range("B" & k + 1).Value = MyString
    End If
Next j

End Function
```

FYI for testing I populated the arrays with the following:

```
ArrayA = Array(123, 456, 789)
ArrayB = Array(123, 567, 912)
ArrayC = Array(456, 789, 567)
```

And the result was:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good use case for dictionaries:

```
ArrayA(1) = 123
ArrayA(2) = 234
ArrayB(1) = 345
ArrayB(2) = 123
ArrayB(3) = 567
ArrayC(1) = 123
ArrayC(2) = 789
ArrayC(3) = 567

'...

Dim e, dictArrays, dictOut, k

Set dictArrays = Createobject("scripting.dictionary")
Set dictOut = Createobject("scripting.dictionary")

dictArrays.Add "A", ArrayA
dictArrays.Add "B", ArrayB
dictArrays.Add "C", ArrayC

For Each k in dictArrays.Keys
    For Each e in dictArrays(k)
        If dictOut.Exists(e) then
           dictOut(e) = dictOut(e) & "," & k  
        Else
           dictOut.Add e, k
        End If
    Next e
Next k

'output the result
For Each k in dictOut.Keys
    Debug.Print k, dictOut(k)
Next k
```